# Add Links to data rows result on Datatables using ASP VB.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net, datatables

I am using DataTables for my ASP project, I would like to have the first column to contain links. 
Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(CardCode),
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/WebServices/Invoice/BusinessPartner.asmx/GetJsonPrevTrans",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: 
    function (ef1) {
        console.log(CardCode);
        console.log(JSON.parse(ef1.d))
        console.log(ef1)
        $("#bpPrevJSONTrans").val(ef1.d).trigger('change');
        var parsed = JSON.parse(ef1.d);
            var bpPrevDt = $('#bpPrevTransData').DataTable({
                retrieve: true,
                responsive: true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bProcessing" : true,
                "aaData": parsed,
                "aoColumns": [
                  { "sTitle": "Test", "mData": "test" },
                  { "sTitle" : "Document Number","mData": "DocNum" },
                  { "sTitle" : "Description", "mData": "Dscription" },
                  { "sTitle": "Amount", "mData": "DocTotal", "sType": "numeric" }
                ]
            });  
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: "_I would like to have the first column to contain links_" - what links, and what to base those links on?

Comment: Hi david, I just redo the code and instead of putting a link on the row data,I just made the whole row clickable to do my functions with the fnRowCallBack function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Test one to contain a link then change the `aoColumns` arrays 1st element to below line,

```
{ "sTitle": "Test", 
  "mData": "test", 
  "fnRender":function(obj, type){
      return "<a href='Your link goes here' >Click here</a>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a link button in row details for me to do my function such as editing, I just used the fnRowCallBack function of the datatable. See code below:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {

                // Bind click event
                $(nRow).click(function () {
                    $('#viewInvoiceEntry').modal('show');
                    //Append Information on Modal:
                    $('#viewInvRefNum').val(aData.DocNum).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    $('#viewInvDesc').val(aData.Dscription).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    $('#viewInvAmnt').val(aData.DocTotal).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    $('#viewInvDocDate').val(aData.DocDate).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    $('#viewInvSrvc').val(aData.ItemName).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    $('#viewInvCompGrp').val(aData.GroupName).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    $('#viewInvCompName').val(aData.CompName).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    $('#viewInvRemarks').val(aData.Comments).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                    //alert('You clicked on ' + aData.DocNum + '\'s row');

                });

                return nRow;
            }
```